# WebRTC audio heard without <audio> element (RTCMultiConnection)

Tags: html, audio, webrtc

Audio is being heard even though no audio element seems to be put inserted in the DOM.

Scenario:

1. Create PeerConnection without streams
2. Add a stream but disable the code that adds MediaElements (audio,video) to DOM

Issue:

3. After the stream gets across, audio can be heard from headphones (or speakers).

What should happen:

4. Since I'm not attaching anything to the dom I expect no audio to be heard.

[Code for replicating the scenario](http://jsfiddle.net/pzw6782L/)

```
// <body>
//   <script src="https://cdn.webrtc-experiment.com/RTCMultiConnection.js"></script>
//   <button id="start">Start!</button>
// </body>

$('#start').click(function() {
  var NO_MEDIA_SESSION = {video: false, audio: false, oneway: true};

  var caller = new RTCMultiConnection('lets-try');
  caller.session = NO_MEDIA_SESSION;
  caller.dontAttachStream = true;
  caller.onstream = function() { console.log("Got stream but not attaching") };  

  var receiver = new RTCMultiConnection('lets-try');
  receiver.session = NO_MEDIA_SESSION;
  receiver.dontAttachStream = true;
  receiver.onstream = function() { console.log("Got stream but not attaching") };  

  caller.open();
  receiver.connect();

  receiver.onconnected = function() {
    console.log("Connected!");
    caller.addStream({audio: true});
  }
});
```

I'm interested how is it possible to hear MediaStream without there being *audio* DOM element?
If any RTCMultiConnection specialists answering, then maybe point me how to avoid audio stream being made audible? (I want to get the stream and attach it later myself).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RTCMultiConnection creates `mediaElement` on the fly to make sure `onstream` event is fired only when media stream started flowing.

```
connection.onstream = function(event) {
    event.mediaElement.pause(); // or volume=0

    // or
    event.mediaElement = null;

    // or
    delete event.mediaElement;
};
```

### Updated:

Use following snippet:

```
var connection = new RTCMultiConnection();

connection.session = {
    data: true
};

btnOpenRoom.onclick = function() {
    connection.open('roomid');
};

btnJoinRoom.onclick = function() {
    connection.join('roomid');
};

btnAddAudioStream.onclick = function() {
    connection.addStream({
        audio: true
    });
};

btnAddAudioVideoStream.onclick = function() {
    connection.addStream({
        audio: true,
        video: true
    });
};
```

Comment: Thank you. That solves the issue. Also came to the conclusion myself - user will hear audio if the created MediaElement (audio or video) has #play called. So as you suggested calling #pause, setting volume to 0 (or not calling #play) will do it. (https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/blob/881383e4dd376e94fce080c04b258841e9cd6723/RTCMultiConnection/latest.js#L4158) My assumption was wrong that the MediaElement needs to be attached to DOM.

Comment: Created another example demonstrating that attaching to dom is not necessary, though removing from DOM will stop audio. http://jsfiddle.net/2113jvr9/